# Beginner need some advice how to write code in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 2d-games

I'm a beginner in programming world, never touch any programming language before. But last 3 days I decide to try make a flash game, I looked some tutorial about AS3, try it, yes I understand a little bit. But I'm still confused about this:

- How do I know or to decide what codes I write first, what next? example: I want to add a hero, then a enemy, then a tiles, then a background, event listener.
- Is it okay if I write code randomly, example: first I add enemy, then add tiles, add background, then add hero, etc?
- What is the best way to completely learn all AS3 codes, especially about flash game dev?

I'm now in frustration mode, so I decide to learn from you all who have mastered AS3.

Comment: As an experienced AS3 developer it's sad to say this, but learning AS3 is not a good investment. You will get more out of learning JavaScript.

Comment: But JavaScript games need own hosting right? Maybe i'll learn it later when i have made some flash games with AS3.

Comment: You can upload your own JavaScript games to many places like [GameJolt](http://gamejolt.com/) etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this guide by Michael James Williams](http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/as3-avoider-game-tutorial-base/). I was in the same situation as you, and that guide helped me a lot. It goes through a lot of the basics and does a good job of explaining each step.

To answer some of your questions, the order in which you code stuff doesn't matter too much. You can always go back and adjust your old code, and you'll definitely end up doing that at some point.

For learning AS3 syntax, just look through some examples and tutorials, and don't be afraid to read the [official AS3 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html). They might be intimidating at first, but once you start learning some of the terminology, they're very helpful.

Comment: Yes, i already looked to MJW tutorial before you told me, and it's awesome, but i still confused about some things. Thanks.

Comment: What are you having trouble with, specifically?

Comment: Sometimes i got confused and don't have a clue in what class i must add the scripts or event or function.

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

you can try some video tutorials like these

http://www.lynda.com/ActionScript-tutorials/AS3-language-fundamentals/123492/129625-4.html

http://www.lynda.com/Flash-tutorials/Building-Flash-Games-Starling/98951-2.html?srchtrk=index:1%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq:flash%2Bgames%0Apage:1%0As:relevance%0Asa:true%0Aproducttypeid:2

Comment: you can pay 25/ month for lynda.com or you can use this book http://books.google.com/books?id=gUHX2fcLKxYC&pg=PR16&lpg=PR16&dq=essential+actionscript+3.0+pdf&source=bl&ots=cvYX2lbSB4&sig=kSdxbSrVJFQp37b_kWXX9F0liS0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QZVJU6C5FuWb3AW6_YHoCw&sqi=2&ved=0CHoQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=essential%20actionscript%203.0%20pdf&f=false

Answer (score 0):

If you're frustrated NOW, are you sure that you're ready to invest a couple of YEARS in becoming half-good with Actionscript?  You'll have to like learning from your mistakes (an excellent way to learn, actually), because you will make thousands of them and they will cost you thousands of hours!

Do NOT write 'randomly' unless you want to greatly lengthen your time to mastery. Everything you do should have a purpose. I would start (if I were starting again) by giving myself a series of the smallest challenges: make an object appear; make it disappear; make it appear in one second from now; make it appear when I tap a key or click my mouse; make it move across the screen; make it move back; make it follow my mouse... etc.

There are many hundreds of basic programmatic elements like these that will add to your growing grasp of logic, data-structures and language. There are usually many ways to accomplish the same task -- learn and practice all of them.

Luckily, the Internet is full of good tutorials and references to Actionscript, and some decent forums like this one where you can get help.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i will try harder from now. I'm frustrated because i want to earn it quickly and when i had learned it i want to teach some people in my city to learn it for free, because in my city i can't find any AS3 programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is king of old but someone might still find this useful.

I think that if you are serious about game development and also want to learn some techniques that are independent of the platform (Flash/AS3 in this case) you should use a framework.

For Flash the best game framework is the [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) along with [Feather](http://feathersui.com/) for UI.

They run on Stage3D which means that run on the GPU not the CPU which make them very fast.

With Starling you can also create mobile games that run in AIR so I think it really is something to consider.

On [hsharma.com](http://www.hsharma.com/games/hungry-hero-a-new-starling-game/) you can find a free video tutorial that goes through everything you need to know to get starting with game development so it should answer the question on how to create enemies, backgrounds, etc.

Hope this helps someone.